# The Alamofire is not working for a larg image

Tags: ios, xcode, alamofire

I'm using alamofire framework to upload image/ video to server and when I'm trying to upload captured image through iphone 6s the image can not be uploaded but when I'm trying to upload small image it's working very good , What is the maximum size that is supported by alamofire and if we don't have maximum size how I can solve this problem ?

```
func uploadFile()  {

    //let image = UIImage(named: "ios9.jpg")
    let newimage : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image.image!, 32)!

    let newRandomName = randomStringWithLength(32)
    let fname = (newRandomName as String) + ".jpg"

    let parameters = [
        "pic"           :NetData(data: newimage, mimeType: .ImageJpeg, filename: fname),
        "msg"     :self.msg,
        "customer_key" : self.CUSTOMER_KEY
    ]



    let urlRequest = self.urlRequestWithComponents("myURLhere", parameters: parameters)

    Alamofire.upload(urlRequest.0, data: urlRequest.1)
        .progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
            print("\(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")
        }
        .responseJSON { response in
            debugPrint(response)
    }

}


func urlRequestWithComponents(urlString:String, parameters:NSDictionary) -> (URLRequestConvertible, NSData) {

    // create url request to send
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlString)!)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = Alamofire.Method.POST.rawValue
    //let boundaryConstant = "myRandomBoundary12345"
    let boundaryConstant = "NET-POST-boundary-\(arc4random())-\(arc4random())"
    let contentType = "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundaryConstant
    mutableURLRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")


    // create upload data to send
    let uploadData = NSMutableData()

    // add parameters
    for (key, value) in parameters {

        uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

        if value is NetData {
            // add image
            let postData = value as! NetData




            // append content disposition
            let filenameClause = " filename=\"\(postData.filename)\""
            let contentDispositionString = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\";\(filenameClause)\r\n"
            let contentDispositionData = contentDispositionString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentDispositionData!)


            // append content type
            //uploadData.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!) // mark this.
            let contentTypeString = "Content-Type: \(postData.mimeType.getString())\r\n\r\n"
            let contentTypeData = contentTypeString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            uploadData.appendData(contentTypeData!)
            uploadData.appendData(postData.data)

        }else{
            uploadData.appendData("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n\(value)".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
    }
    uploadData.appendData("\r\n--\(boundaryConstant)--\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)




    return (Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: nil).0, uploadData)
}



func randomStringWithLength (len : Int) -> NSString {

    let letters : NSString = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

    var randomString : NSMutableString = NSMutableString(capacity: len)

    for (var i=0; i < len; i++){
        var length = UInt32 (letters.length)
        var rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
        randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
    }

    return randomString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Alamofire.upload(
        .POST,
        "your url",
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in


            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: imageData!, name: "garment_image", fileName: "myImage.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") // image



        },
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .Success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.progress { (bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite) in
                    print("Uploading Avatar \(totalBytesWritten) / \(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)")

                print(upload.response)
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{


                        /**
                         *  Update UI Thread about the progress
                         */
                    })
                }
                upload.responseJSON { (JSON) in
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                        //Show Alert in UI

                    })
                }

            case .Failure( _):
                //Show Alert in UI
                print("Avatar failed");
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer and what is the difference will be notice after that and what is the maximum size can I upload it through framework as I asked above !